# Simulate user keystrokes in Visual Studio Code Extension Testing

Tags: vscode-extensions

For testing my extension, which is an editor emulator and keymap. I'd like to simulate some user input and make sure the extension reacts as expected. Is that possible? I have done a lot of searching and I am not finding a solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm late, but you can try following codes:

```
// 1. open some file
const uri = vscode.Uri.file('/full/path/of/file');
await vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(uri);

// 2. focus on editor
await vscode.window.showTextDocument(uri);

// 3. go to line x and column y
const position = new vscode.Position(10, 28);
editor.selection = new vscode.Selection(position, position);

// 4. input some text
const inputText = 'some sample text';
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('type', { text: inputText });
```